# Capitalized Italic I Followed by Logical Term in Parentheses

Tags: abstract-algebra

Does a capitalized italic I followed by a logical term in parentheses have a special meaning in maths?

I was reading equations associated with tree boosting as solutions to exercises in the book Introduction to Statistical Learning. The solutions are at the link below.  The equations under solution 2 have examples of the capitalized italic I followed by parentheses.

I wondered if this has a consistent special meaning?

https://rpubs.com/ppaquay/65564

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this likely refers to the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). In particular, $I(x_1 < t_1)$ is $1$ if $x_1 < t_1$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: The function is what I expected but it's really good to have a name for it.